# Why this stored procedure return an empty result?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that it works correctly on localhost but when i tried to execute that on my vps server, i give an empty result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_contest_selectContestId`(
IN _uniquetitle VARCHAR(300))
BEGIN
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `contest`
    WHERE 
        `uniquetitle` = _uniquetitle
    LIMIT 0, 1
;END
```

When i use this part without using procedure with the same data to test, i have not any problem:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `contest`
WHERE 
    `uniquetitle` = _uniquetitle
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: i have several stored procedure on my vps and there is no problem just this one.

Comment: Oh!! yes, its same, when i use only this part "SELECT `id`
    FROM `contest`
    WHERE 
        `uniquetitle` = _uniquetitle
    LIMIT 0, 1" there is no problem

Comment: No OUT parameter? No AS (or IS) keyword?

Comment: i have other procedure same this one without OUT or AS or IS but no problem.

Comment: Check your permissions - the userid who is running the stored procedure (the definer) may not have permissions on the db you are querying.

Answer (score 1):

I was using UTF-8 data. My tables was UTF8 but not my database. database was latin_swedish.

I change my database collation to UTF8 and then import my data again. problem solved.

I had to set mydatabase collation to UTF-8 befor insert or import any things.